# Counting the number of elements

Tags: string-manipulation, code-request, counting, code

I have the following output:

```
{{{0, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 3}}, {{3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}}}
```

Using `Length[]` on this, gives `5`. But I want to get the number of all possibilities so I want the number `9`. How do I manipulate a code using `Length[]`?

Comment: `{{{0, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 3}}, {{3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 
     3}, {3, 4}}}~Level~{-2} // Length`

Comment: also `Count[#,{__Integer},2]@lists`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check each length and add them up. See the function f below:

```
f = Total@*Map[Length]
f[{{{0, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 3}}, {{3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}}}]
```

gives

```
9
```